# Can \left( ... \right) be instructed to ignore nonexistent upper or lower limits of summation?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, delimiters

In a formula such as

```
\[ \left( \sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}} \right) \]
```

the left and right delimiters extend not only downwards to cover the lower limit of the sum, but upwards an equal amount as if to cover an upper limit, despite there being no upper limit.  Is there a way to prevent this?

This seems related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25445/is-there-a-way-to-modify-the-default-vertical-spacing-conventions-of-latex-left/25450#25450), and the first answer there (enclose it in an `array` environment) can sort of solve it, but (I think) inelegantly, and also inserts extra spacing.  I'm hoping there is a better way, like a command to simply control whether `\sum` has a top delimiter at all or something.

Comment: When dealing with the issue of placing large parentheses around a displaystyle-sized summation symbol in one of the math-related chapters of the *TeXbook*, Knuth explicitly recommends using `\biggl( ... \biggr)` rather than `\left( ... \right)`. I.e., the size of the "fences" chosen by `\left( ... \right)` are too large.

Comment: I agree, generally size the fences such that it is clear what they fence in, but not such that they dominate the expression. As for sums, there is no need for the fences to encapsulate the limits.

Comment: The issue isn't so much that the parentheses are too large, it's that they are off-center vertically: they include lots of empty space at the top.  Manually choosing a size doesn't change that.

Comment: @MikeShulman - I'd argue that TeX is *not* placing the parentheses off-center vertically, irrespective of their (insufficient, correct, or exaggerated) size: note that the "bellies" of the parentheses are lined up with the middle of the large operator symbol in all cases. Moreover, I'd argue that it's neither necessary nor desirable to enclose the (lower and/or upper) limits of summation with parentheses, lest the fences dominate the entire expression. Hence the recommendation to use `\bigg` as the explicit size instruction.

Comment: I kind of object to being told that my question is wrong. This is what I want to do -- the question is whether it can be done.  Personally, I think it looks ugly and confusing _not_ to enclose the limits of summation in the parentheses.

Comment: Would it make you any happier if I mentioned that in the example I really care about, the delimiters are not parentheses but rather (double) vertical bars?  I just thought it would be simpler to give an example where the delimiters are more familiar.

Comment: Probably duplicate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1023/484

Comment: @Charles: Thanks!!  I searched before asking but didn't find your question.  Somehow you managed to get much more helpful answers than I did.

Comment: @CharlesStaats -- that question does cover exactly the same territory, but the images in the answers to this question make the possibilities much more obvious.  this is a good candidate for "consolidation", but i haven't got time to do it justice.

Answer (score 4):

Is it one of the following?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \Bigl(\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}}\Bigr)
  \biggl(\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}}\biggr)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the fence size produced by `\Biggl( ... \Biggr)` is the same as that produced by `\left( ... `\right)`, and given that the OP has already declared that size to be too large, the third option should definitely *not* be considered.

Comment: @Mico Good point; I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The issue isn't just that the parentheses are too large, it's that they are off-center vertically.

Answer (score 4):

Parentheses are placed symmetrically with respect to the math axis, an imaginary line a bit over the baseline, that can be seen by typesetting a fraction, because the fraction line lies exactly on the math axis.

A problem with fences around an expressions such as

```
\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}} 2^n
\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}} \frac{2^n-1}{2^n+1}
```

depends on the whole expression to be enclosed.

After observing that `\left(` and `\right)` will give poor results, the choice can be between `\Big` and `\bigg`. Here's a visual comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\Bigl(\,\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}} 2^n\Bigr)
\quad
\biggl(\,\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}} 2^n\biggr)
\\[6pt]
\Bigl(\,\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}} \frac{2^n-1}{2^n+1}\Bigr)
\quad
\biggl(\,\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}} \frac{2^n-1}{2^n+1}\biggr)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd probably use `\Big` for the first kind of formula and `\bigg` for the second one.

Something like

```
\[
2+\left( \raisebox{1.5mm}{$\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}}2^{-n}$} \right)=4
\]
```

that produces

[image]

is clearly unacceptable. Nor is better

```
\[
2+\raisebox{-1.5mm}{$\displaystyle
  \left( \raisebox{1.5mm}{$\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}}2^{-n}$} \right)$}=4
\]
```

[image]

Comment: As I said, what I want is for the delimiters to enclose the lower limit, but not any extra space for the upper limit.

Comment: @MikeShulman I find no reason for this.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: @MikeShulman Look at the new examples to see what I mean. A parenthesized subformula makes sense only when set in context.

Comment: @Mike (and egreg, but you'll be notified automatically): It seems to me that the last option might well look better with double vertical bar delimiters rather than parentheses. The OP has said that in the case he really cares about, he's using double bar delimiters.

Comment: @CharlesStaats I don't change my opinion even for bars. `;-)`

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion, but it's only an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to do what I want in the test case, at least:

```
\[ \left( \raisebox{1.5mm}{$\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbf{N}}$} \right) \]
```

But I don't understand why, and it seems a bit kludgy.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend such a construction, which is *more* kludgy than using `\biggl` and `\biggr`.

Comment: Since `\biggl` and `\biggr` don't solve the problem, their relative kludginess seems irrelevant.

Comment: You surely have something beside the summation sign.

Comment: Yeah, so it has to go in the `\raisebox` too, I guess.